# How do I put files in folders while using Eliom?

Tags: ocaml, ocsigen

I am beginning to develop a website in ocaml using Eliom. As the project grows, I want to be able to split off different segments of the code into different files and then group these files into folders. I figured out how to split off into different files: In Makefile.options, I change the line:

```
SERVER_FILES := $(wildcard *.eliomi *.eliom)
```

to

```
SERVER_FILES := $(wildcard *.eliomi *.eliom) file.ml
```

However, I can't figure out how to be able to use .ml files that are in folders. If I naively use:

```
SERVER_FILES := $(wildcard *.eliomi *.eliom) folder/file.ml
```

I get the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create _deps/folder/.server: Directory nonexistent
```

And even if I manually create this file and build again, I get the error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Unbound module File
```

Is there some way I can access files that I put into folders?